# Show 1-to-1 correspondence between sufficient statistic and sample mean/variance

Tags: probability-theory

Say we $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be identically distributed independent random variables (the example they're using is $X_i\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$), with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. My book says there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between
$$
\left(\sum_iX_i,\sum_iX_i^2\right)\text{ and }\left(1/n\sum_iX_i,(n-1)^{-1}\sum_i\left(X_i-\overline X\right)^2\right).
$$
Now I can see the 1-to-1 correspondence between the first entries of the two vectors. However, how I don't see how we have a bijection between $\sum_iX_i^2$ and the sample variance. I mean, we have
$$
(X_i-\overline X)=X_i^2+\overline X^2-2X_i\overline X=X_i^2+1/n^2\left(\sum_iX_i\right)^2-2X_i\cdot1/n\sum_iX_i.
$$
Maybe it's easy to show, but I'm not sure if what I'm doing right now is the right approach.

If I write $(a,b)$ for $\left(\sum_iX_i,\sum_iX_i^2\right)$, then basically I want to show that
$$
(a,b)\mapsto\left(\frac{1}{n}a,\frac{1}{n-1}b+\frac{1}{n^2(n-1)}a^2-\frac{2}{n(n-1)}a^2 \right)
$$
is a bijection. If this is all correct, the only possible issue would be $a^2$. But I'm kind of stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ given by
$$f(a,b) = \left( \frac{1}{n} a , \frac{1}{n-1}b + \left(\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{2}{n(n-1)}\right) a^2 \right)$$ is injective, suppose that $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$. Since the first coordinates of the images have to be equal we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{n} a = \frac{1}{n} c
$$
which gives $a = c$. We also know that
$$
\frac{1}{n-1}b + \left(\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{2}{n(n-1)}\right) a^2 = 
\frac{1}{n-1}d + \left(\frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{2}{n(n-1)}\right) c^2
$$
and now we can use that we already know $a=c$. Hence we obtain $\frac{1}{n-1} b = \frac{1}{n-1} d$ and therefore $b=d$.
We conclude that $(a,b) = (c,d)$, so $f$ is injective.

Can you finish the proof by showing $f$ is surjective?